# trying to use custom user model with django-allauth framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

i have a custom user  model that looks like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


# user manager code
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, first name,
        last name and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            **extra_fields,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

# Create your models here.


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

my serializer.py

```
class RegisteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(style={"input_type": "password"},
                                     write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={"input_type": "password"},
                                      write_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=allauth_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(min_length=2, max_length=50)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(min_length=2, max_length=50)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            "email",
            "password",
            "password2",
        ]

        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def validate_email(self, email):
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            if email and email_address_exists(email):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    ("A user is already registered with this e-mail address."))
        return email

    def validate_password(self, password):
        return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password'] != data['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                ("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return data

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'first_name': self.validated_data.get('first_name', ''),
            'last_name': self.validated_data.get('last_name', ''),
            'password': self.validated_data.get('password', ''),
            'password2': self.validated_data.get('password', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
        }

    def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])
        user.save()
        return user
```

when i register using endpoint  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dj-rest-auth/registration/`
i am greeted with all fields the way i want it

but when i try to login  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dj-rest-auth/login/`
i still see username

even after configuring my django allauth

```
# django-allauth configuarations

ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = True
```

i am new to django rest framework i dont want to rewrite everything i dont even know how

Comment: here is an example of using allauth+DRF https://github.com/wsvincent/drfx/blob/master/config/settings.py, hope that helps

Comment: no it did not infact it is the opposite of what i want

Comment: what is you progress so far?

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: @Bhubanghimire oh yes I was able to solve it...do you need help with it or you wanted to help with it